# Regex to match a word containing all of specified characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regex to match a word that contains all letters contained in a certain set.

For example, if the set contains {A,C,T} then the following would be matches: ACT, CAT, TACT, ... However, the following would not match: CAB, TAN, CUT.

My first attempt is as follows, but it seems way too cumbersome, especially as the set size increases. For example, to match {J,X}:

```
string pattern = @"((\w?)J(\w?)X(\w?))|((\w?)X(\w?)J(\w?))";
```

Is there anything more parsimonious?

Comment: Do you have to use regex for this?

Comment: Ideally. I know I can do something like the following but I need to be able to generate the code dynamically based on the user inputting the set. if (word.Contains("J") && word.Contains("X"))

Answer (score 2):

You can try with lookaheads:

```
(?=.*A)(?=.*C)(?=.*T).{3}
```

http://regex101.com/r/iO7hV1